# Can I add or remove a @RequestMapping dynamically on spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a project on a pure JAX-RS where when I start the service the same search for annotations on lib/plugins/*.jar and add dynamically the @Path to the project depending on some arguments. Can I do something like that on spring-boot dynamically ? If you guys have some code or documentation where I can preceed I appreciate it

Comment: Is it the same for you to enable/disable the whole controller or you want to disable specific API?

Comment: Not that I have anything in mind just yet, but what do you mean by "when I start the service" – how is starting those services triggered if not by the start of the application?

Comment: @MichalM when the service starts, it looks in the folder for all classes that have the "customannotation" annotation, and adds this class as an "Path" in my service. I have an application where I update my client dynamically by uploading the .jar file and each type of annotation and added it differently in my service. I started studying Spring and it seems a good idea to migrate through distributed tools, and it's easier to implement monitoring

Comment: Have you considered an OSGi container then? Seems like a perfect match